# By inspection find a particular solution of $y''+2y=−4x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By inspection find a particular solution of  $y''+2y=−4x$.

Write the answer in the form  $a_nx^n+\ldots+a_0$ with the highest degree order.

I know how to do this when there's one variable, by finding the value of $y$, but when there are two I'm not sure if I have to find the value of both $x$ and $y$ or ...?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: From the RHS, it would seem that a particular solution $y=f(x)$ should be a polynomial. What degree can the highest-order term have?

Comment: y=-2x? and it seems as though it would be degree one no? @rogerl

Comment: That's right. Does that answer your question?

Comment: How do I then write it in the form they're asking. That part is also confusing me.

Comment: I assume that they are looking for $-2x$ as an answer; that is (using their notation) $a_1 = -2$ and all other $a_i=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use the method of undetermined coefficients, where the solution will be the sum of complementary solution (homogenous solution) and the particular solution.

Let $y=e^{\lambda x}$

$$\frac{d^2}{d^2x}(e^{\lambda x}) + 2e^{\lambda x}= 0$$

I'll leave the solution as an exercise, but you should get some function of $Y$ that requires Euler's identity.

Next, you find the particular solution, often denoted as $y_p$. In this case, the particular solution will take the form $y_p (x) = a_1 + a_2 x$. You can plug this into your differential equation and solve for $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Then let $y = y_h + y_p$ and that is your implicit solution. Solve for any constants with initial conditions as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

If you attempt to solve the differential equation you want to solve for

$$ y(x) = y_{h} + y_{p} \tag{1} $$

if we solve the homogeneous solve we can look at the characteristic equation

$$ e^{\lambda x}(r^{2} + 2) =  0 \\ r^{2} + 2 = 0 \\ r = \pm  \sqrt{2}\tag{2}  $$
which gives us

$$ y_{h} = c_{1}\cos(\sqrt{2}x) + c_{2}\sin(\sqrt{2}x) \tag{3} $$

then to find the particular solution we have

$$ y_{p} = c_{1} + c_{2}x \tag{4} $$

to find this we plug it back into the equation

$$ y_{p}^{''}(x) + 2y_{p} = -4x \tag{5} $$

$$ y_{p}^{''}(x) = 0  \\ 2y_{p} = -4x $$
simply solve this

$$ 2c_{1} +2c_{2}x = -4x \implies  c_{1} = 0  \tag{6}$$

$$ 2c_{2} = -4 \implies c_{2} = -2 \\ y_{p} = -2x \tag{7} $$

then we get

$$ y  = y_{h} +y_{p} = c_{1}\cos(\sqrt{2}x) + c_{2}\sin(\sqrt{2}x) -2x \tag{8}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y''+2y=−4x\implies (D^2+2)y=-4x$$

Roots of the trial solution are  $~±i~\sqrt2~$ .

Complementary function (C.F.) is $$c_1~\cos(\sqrt2~x)+c_2~\sin(\sqrt2~x)\qquad \text{where $~c_1~$ and $~c_2~$are  constants.}$$

Particular integral (P.I.) is

P.I. $~=~\frac{1}{D^2+2}~(-4x)$

$~=~-4~\frac{1}{D^2+2}~x$

$~=~-4~\cdot\frac{1}{2}~(1+\frac{D^2}{2})^{-1}~x$

$~=~-2~(1-\frac{D^2}{2}+\cdots)~x$

$~=~-2~x$

Hence the general solution is$$y(x)=\text{C.F.}~+~\text{P.I.}$$
 $$y(x)=c_1~\cos(\sqrt2~x)+c_2~\sin(\sqrt2~x)~-2~x$$where $~c_1~$ and $~c_2~$are  constants.

Answer (score 0):

Try to absorb the right side into the lowest derivative term on the left. That is, take $u(x)=y(x)+2x$ as new variable. Then
$$
u''(x)+2u(x)=y''(x)+2y(x)+4x=0
$$
and from the solution $u=0$ we get the particular solution $y(x)=-2x$.