# Second-order linear ODE $x''+4x=\sin^22t$ with initial conditions help.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x''+4x=\sin^22t$$
$x'(0)=1$, $x(0)=0$.

I know the solution because of wolframalpha but I do not know how they got the solution. Can anyone help by writing out the steps?

Comment: Didn't you just post this problem?

Comment: @AdrianKeister yes but the first time I posted it, one of the variables was incorrect lol

Comment: Well, we generally edit questions here, rather than delete and re-post.

Comment: May help https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2957039/108128

Comment: @Nosrati thank you

Answer (score 1):

The right-hand side is $\frac12-\frac12\cos 4t$, so the general solution is $x(t)=\frac18+\frac{1}{24}\cos4t+C\cos 2t+S\sin 2t$. We find $C,\,S$ from $$\frac16+C=x(0)=0,\,2S=\left.\left(-\frac16\sin 4t-2C\sin 2t+2S\cos 2t\right)\right|_{t=0}=x^\prime(0)=1,$$i.e. $x(t)=\frac18+\frac{1}{24}(\cos4t-4\cos 2t)+\frac12\sin 2t$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x''+4x=\sin^2(2t)\implies(D^2+4)x=\sin^2(2t)\qquad ........(1)$$

Roots of the trial solution are $~\pm2i~$.

Complementary function (C.F.) is $$c_1~\cos (2t)~+~c_2~\sin (2t)\qquad \text{where $~c_1~$ and $~c_2~$are  constants} $$

For Particular Integral (P.I.) is

P.I.$~=\frac{1}{D^2+4}\sin^2(2t)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{D^2+4} (1-\cos(4t))$

$~~~~~~~=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{D^2+4}\cdot 1~-~\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{D^2+4}~\cos(4t)$

$~~~~~~~=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{4}~(1+\frac{D^2}{4})^{-1}\cdot 1~-~\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{-4^2+4}~\cos(4t)$

$~~~~~~~=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{4}~(1-\frac{D^2}{4}+\cdots)~ 1~+~\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{12}~\cos(4t)$

$~~~~~~~=\frac{1}{8}~+~\frac{1}{24}~\cos(4t)$

General solution of the given differential equation $(1)$ is $$x(t)=\text{C.F.}~+~\text{P.I.}$$
$$x(t)=c_1~\cos (2t)~+~c_2~\sin (2t)~+~\frac{1}{8}~+~\frac{1}{24}~\cos(4t)$$where $~c_1~$ and $~c_2~$are  constants.

Given that $~x'(0)=1,\quad x(0)=0$

So we have $~c_1=~-~\frac{1}{8}~-~\frac{1}{24}~=~-~\frac{1}{6}~$

and $~c_2= ~\frac{1}{2}$

Hence  $$x(t)=~-~\frac{1}{6}~\cos (2t)~+~\frac{1}{2}~\sin (2t)~+~\frac{1}{8}~+~\frac{1}{24}~\cos(4t)$$
$$=~\frac{1}{8}+~\frac{1}{2}~\sin (2t)~+~\frac{1}{24}~\left\{\cos(4t)~-~4~\cos (2t)\right\}$$

---

${}$

For the Particular Integral (i.e., P.I.) of trigonometric functions  you have to follow the following rules:

> If $f(D)$ can be expressed as $\phi(D^2)$ and $\phi(-a^2)\neq 0$, then
>
> $1.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \sin ax=\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \sin ax = \frac{1}{\phi(-a^2)} \sin ax$
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \cos ax=\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \cos ax = \frac{1}{\phi(-a^2)} \cos ax$